# Validation of a point (WGS84) within geometry field on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, geography, wgs84

I have been trying to validate if a WGS84 point is inside a geometry field on SQL Server 2012.

The scenario is this, I have the political delimitation of a geographyc zone in a SQL Server 2012 database (postal code and everything), validated.

Then, I have also, points in WGS84 system locating some infraestructure with, postal codes submmited by providers, that I want to validate.

I need to validate if each point (WGS84) belong to the postal code submmited with it.

I have no idea where to start.

Thanks for the help!.

Omar

Comment: Omar, can you provide a little more information that better helps me understand your requirements please?  For example I'm not entirely sure what you mean by validate Postcodes.  Can you also supply the country you need to do it for?

Comment: Thank you Jon, in other words, I have 2 tables, First, one with delimitation of cities all across the country (Peru) this data came from exporting ARCGIS shape and its a geometry and another field with the correspondant postal code of that delimitation.
Second, another table with reports from suppliers with a georeferenced (WGS84) point in a field and another field with a postal code they claim it to be in.
We detected that the data in the second table was not well formed, so, the postal code did not correspond to the georeferenced point. So before they send us data, we need to validate it.

Comment: So the boundaries in the first table, are they city boundaries, or Postal Code boundaries with a City reference?

Comment: In the first table, the postal codes boundaries match city (district) boundaries... we call them cities, but its more like districts for your reference... I apologize for the confusion...

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm starting to understand it now.  So the key here is that you want to be able to say "Is this Point (in table 2) within the Geometry (in table 1) that matches the Postal Code sent with the Point (in table 2)" - correct?  If so, one more question, when you say the table 1 field is geometry, is it actually geometry, or geometric shapes within a Geography field?

Comment: ACRGIS exported the data as **Geometry Field** in SQL Server (being weird, that the spatial results shows latitude and longitude grids correctly)

Comment: OK, based on what I understand, see how the answer below helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your life easier you'll need to first alter table 1 to include a geography column, which will hold the converted geometry data.  You can convert as follows:

```
UPDATE [Table1] SET [NewGeographyColumn] = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromWKB([GeometryColumn].STAsBinary(), 4326);
```

Now that you have a Geography column with a matching SRID to your Table2 Points, ensure you create a SpatialIndex on this new column.

You can then run a spatial query to ensure that your received data is correct:

```
DECLARE @receivedLatitude DOUBLE = 0;
DECLARE @receivedLongitude DOUBLE = 0;
DECLARE @receivedPostalCodeName VARCHAR(10) = 'Postcode';

DECLARE @receivedPoint GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@receivedLatitude, @receivedLongitude, 4326);

SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE [NewGeographyColumn].STIntersects(@receivedPoint) AND [PostalCodeName] = @receivedPostalCodeName;
```

Or at least something to that effect to validate....

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but for some reason, allways shows 0. Heres my test code:
`DECLARE @receivedLatitude FLOAT = 11.8147; -- DOUBLE
DECLARE @receivedLongitude FLOAT = 74.7838; -- DOUBLE
DECLARE @receivedPostalCodeName VARCHAR(10) = '120135';
DECLARE @receivedPoint GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@receivedLatitude, @receivedLongitude, 4326);
SELECT [NewGeographyColumn].STIntersects(@receivedPoint), * FROM [dbo].[CIUDADES] WHERE [CODIGO] = @receivedPostalCodeName;`
Lat and Long provided belongs to the shown postal code, but when I change Lat to 13 (outside delimitation), STIntersects stills goes 0

Comment: I ran the Update code, and tested and it ran correctly

Comment: Glad it helped.  However I just want to check that you did get it to work in the end?  I'm slightly concerned that your latitude and longitudes should be negatives for Peru (which might explain the 0 result).  Are you getting correct results?

Comment: I meant this code `UPDATE [Table1] SET [NewGeographyColumn] = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromWKB([GeometryColumn].STAsBinary(), 4326);`, but your tottaly right, tested with negative values worked perfectly!, I should know better with lat and long values, this open my eyes to a very common problem with the reported data (some values where reported in negative some values in positive, that I have to resolve somehow) thank you very very much for your patience. This problem has been with me for many weeks...

Answer (score 0):

You could use, for instance, Bing Map REST Services for that.

For each point you would:

- Query the "Find a Location by Point" service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx)
- Use the "PostalCode" field of the response to validate your postal code.

Example (taken from the reference page):

Request:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/47.64054,-122.12934?key=BingMapsKey
```

(The BingMapsKey can be obtained from www.bingmapsportal.com)

Response, which includes the Postal Code:

```
(...)
"address":{
   "addressLine":"1 Microsoft Way",
   "adminDistrict":"WA",
   "adminDistrict2":"King Co.",
   "countryRegion":"United States",
   "formattedAddress":"1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA 98052",
   "locality":"Redmond",
   "postalCode":"98052"
},
(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but sadly, I have 2 major constraints, first, this development isn't for United States and, second, it will be for a workstation with or without internet connection. I was hoping only use a SQL Query to resolve that...